# QtConcurrent::run with functor

Tags: multithreading, qt, functor, qtconcurrent

How to use QtConcurrent::run with function objects? Can you please show me an example how to do that?

Comment: solved it somehow. A guy on qt irc said that functor must have ::result_type member and it can't be a child of QObject, and it must have a copy ctor.